# Why won't the addEventListener trigger on change?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

Trying to get the eventlistener to run, i.e. when I select United Kingdom, another selection box will appear to select county (county() function), but for some reason the addEventListener will not call the function, and I can't fathom how to pass the selected country to the county function? Any ideas please.

```
                function countries() {
                    xmlRequest("countries.xml");
                    var country_selector = document.createElement("SELECT");
                    country_selector.id = "cou n tryselection";
                    document.getElementById("quiz").appendChild(country_selector);
                    var t = document.getElementById("countryselection");

                    var c_opt = document.createElement("option");
                    c_opt.text = "Please select";
                    c_opt.selected = true;
                    t.add(c_opt);
                    c_opt = document.createElement("option");
                    c_opt.text = "United Kingdom";
                    c_opt.value = "1";
                    t.add(c_opt);
                    document.getElementById("countryselection").addEventListener("change", count y(this.value), false);
                    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("country");
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        var opt = document.createElement("option");
                        opt.text = x[i].getElementsByTagName("country_name ")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        t.add(opt);
                    }
                }

                function county(Country) {
                    if (!document.getElementById("countyselection")) {
                        if (Country === "1") {
                            xmlRequest("counties.xml");
                            document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML += "<select id='countyselection'></select>";
                            var t = document.getElementById("countyselection");
                            var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("county");
                            for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++)
                            {
                                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                                var txt = y[j].getElementsByTagName("county_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                opt.text = txt;
                                t.add(opt);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        var f = document.getElementById("countyselection");
                        document.getElementById("countyselection").parentNode.removeChild(f);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: where's your HTML? If it isn't get called at all, why have you posted so many lines of code? we need a short example which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling the function, not referencing it, and you have a space in the function name.

change

```
document.getElementById("countryselection").addEventListener("change", count y(this.value), false);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("countryselection").addEventListener("change", function() {
    county(this.value);
}, false);
```

---

Also note that things like this

```
country_selector.id = "cou n tryselection";
```

is completely invalid, you can't use random text with spaces as an ID